# Running into Heroku's slug size limit after Ruby and Rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am working on updating my Ruby and Rails to the next minor release (3.3.0 from 3.2.2 and 7.1.2 from 7.0.8 of Ruby and Rails respectively), but am running into Heroics slug size limit.  I am apparently over the limit after compression at 520MB.

My app utilizes Google Text to Speech gem and that apparently depends on the grpc gem, which seems to take up a LOT of space.

Otherwise I don't see what else is causing the issue.  I didn't have any slug warnings before the update to Ruby 3.3.0.  Should I just downgrade to Ruby 3.2.2 for now?

Comment: I went ahead and downgraded to Ruby 3.2.2 and this solved the issue for now.  So it has something to do with GRPC 1.60.0 on Ruby 3.3.0

Comment: the slug went from 520MB to 201MB.

Comment: It appears you have found your own solution. I you believe this would be useful to future visitors, you should post it as answer because many people will gloss over the comments looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to Ruby 3.2.2 vs Ruby 3.3.0 and that is alarming to hear (and potentially a reason to hold off on the upgrade.)

For those who find this question in the future I've had a lot of success reducing my Heroku slug size by using an aggressive .slugignore file and the [Heroku Post-Build Clean Buildpack|https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean]

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index integer_index_based_on_how_many_buildpacks_you_have https://github.com/Lostmyname/heroku-buildpack-post-build-clean.git
```

with the following .slug-post-clean file

```
node_modules
tmp/cache
tmp/cache/webpacker
```

and a .slugignore file like this

```
*.psd
*.pdf
/test
/spec
```

There are a few other commands that also can help you, depending on your issue including

`heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:docker:test"`

`heroku builds:cache:purge`

Per [Thoughtbot|https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-reduce-a-large-heroku-compiled-slug-size] you can also install the Heroku repo plugin which may give you some additional mileage

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
```

Then run:

```
heroku repo:gc --app your-app-name
heroku repo:purge_cache --app your-app-name
```

Heroku advises that you remove any big PDF, PSD or image files from your project also (big images can definitely inflate slug size.)

I've also found the approach outlined in this [blogpost|https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/05/04/how-to-reduce-heroku-slug-size] helpful of adding a custom asset clean task like the example below that removes the node_modules folder after compilation but right before the slug is generated.

```
# cat lib/tasks/assets.rake
# Adapted from https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/792

namespace :assets do
  desc "Remove 'node_modules' folder"
  task rm_node_modules: :environment do
    Rails.logger.info "Removing node_modules folder"
    FileUtils.remove_dir("node_modules", true)
  end
end

skip_clean = %w(no false n f).include?(ENV["WEBPACKER_PRECOMPILE"])

unless skip_clean
  if Rake::Task.task_defined?("assets:clean")
    Rake::Task["assets:clean"].enhance do
      Rake::Task["assets:rm_node_modules"].invoke
    end
  else
    Rake::Task.define_task("assets:clean" => "assets:rm_node_modules")
  end
end
```

Good luck squashing slugs out there (also it does seem like if you recently upgraded to Ruby 3.3.0 from Ruby 3.2.2 like Patrick, just downgrading and seeing if that fixes things is very much worth it.)

Salt those slugs, people!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.slugignore` file on your `root` directory and include the dir/filename that you don't want to deploy on Heroku.

Example:

```
# Ignore these files/paths from being deployed to heroku to reduce slug size
/spec
/tmp/*
```